# How to send the parameter with UDP protocol using twisted

Tags: python, twisted, bittorrent

How to connect to the following url using twisted and get the response from the tracker.
udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce?uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=1&event=started&peer_id=kovid_agarwal1235467&port=6881&info_hash=3389809f0c9096819294a680beb4adb96a738419&left=763922958

I tried the following code but I am getting connection Id mismatch error

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from MakeUrlRequest import  encoded_Value


class SendAndReceiveUDP(DatagramProtocol):

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.connect("31.172.124.3",80)
        self.transport.write(encoded_Value())


    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        print "Received %r" %datagram
from twisted.internet import reactor
udpclient=SendAndReceiveUDP()
reactor.listenUDP(6881,udpclient)
reactor.run()
```

Above the encoded_Value is nothing but the value as follows:
uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=1&event=started&peer_id=kovid_agarwal1235467&port=6881&info_hash=3389809f0c9096819294a680beb4adb96a738419&left=763922958

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_tracker, the UDP-based protocol for exchanging data with Bittorrent trackers uses "a custom binary format".  It doesn't look like the data you're sending conforms to this format.  So the error you receive probably indicates that you need to format your request differently.  See http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html for further details about that format.

Comment: Thanx I got the answer from the following mentioned link. http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html#udp-tracker-protocol

Comment: Thanx Jean for ur support... !